# How to detect a NOT-possible drag-n-drop in WPF applications?

Tags: wpf, windows-7, drag-and-drop, detect

I see some QnAs in our SO discussing about how to detect a drag-n-drop event but sometimes, for some reason such as application A run with admin right whist application B did not, the drag-n-drop is `NOT allowed` by Windows OS.

My question is: How can we detect a `NOT-possible drag-n-drop` happens in our code?

*Edit*

This question is about drag-n-dropping between two applications, one is privileged (run as admin) and other is NOT. Dragging between them is not allowed by Windows OS. I want to detect that situation and pop up a message in my application to let the users know why dragging then is not possible.

Comment: From what side? The source or the destination? The privileged or the non-privileged application?

Comment: @Fernandes: From both sides. Both cases of privileging.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do this using the DragOver event

```
private void UserControl_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  //Verify that this is a valid drop
  if (!Validate())
  {
   e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
   e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a method `Validate()`

Comment: You have to Specify your custom validation routine in that location

Comment: I guess you still misunderstand my question - it is about drag-dropping between two applications, one is privileged (run as admin) and other is NOT. Dragging between them is not allowed by Windows OS. I want to detect that situation and pop up a message in my application to let the users know why dragging then is not possible. Hope myself is clearer now.

Comment: hmm..seems to a different problem altogether